# A javascript function to perform add/append input type of file with array,but PHP fail to execute it

Tags: php, javascript

I going to use a javascript function to perform  add/append  the input type of file with array,but when I use print_r() to determine whether the array is exactly in the index or not,it show me only one index of array is included.The sample output as below:

```
  Array
   (
   [name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20130112891.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3BEA.tmp
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 209825
    )
```

Below HTML code and javascript show that where file array is added/appended:

```
              <tr>
                <th class="title">Image</th>
                <td>:</td>
                <th><input type="file" name="image[]"></th>
            </tr>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addbtn").click(function(){

     $("#tb tr:last th:last").append("<input type=file name=image[]>");
                });


       });

 </script>
```

Sample output after append the file input

[image: Sample output after append the file input]

Comment: try to use quotes when adding new file field. Maybe jQuery clears brackets when appending. Or use `$.clone()`.

Comment: u_mulder You mean add quotes between file like "file" or "image[]"?

Comment: when i do like this....append("<input type="file" name="image[]">"); it will be syntax error on my program(Dreamwaever)

Comment: Sure it's an error. You should use single quotes inside double quotes (as jQuery recommend): `append("<input type='file' name='image[]'>");` or vice versa.

Comment: I had try it,its work but the index of array still one if i append the file input

Comment: Very strange. Can you check source html code after adding new fields?

Comment: yes,i'd found the new file field after after append.